# openx: can't upload banner after moving to new server

Tags: banner, openx

I went through the whole process in order to move openx. My banners are normally displayed and I have full access to administration. The only issue is that when trying to upload a banner, it isn't saved. When returning to the banner properties tab the file is missing. Can you help please? Thanks.

Comment: It says "Error: File permission errors detected.
These may impact the accurate delivery of your ads,
See the debug.log file for the list of unwritable files" but all files are writable, even tried 777 with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may raised after migrate files in to new server then you may not change "webDir" value in your configuration file under "YourOpenX/var/yourdomainame.conf.php" file .

If above mentioned not working then problem should be in "www/images" folder permission.

check and put your comment here if you need any other help.